# Chrome OS - Pinned App

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I developed a small dashboard app for students. Via Google Admin, I pushed the app as a "PINNED" app. However on the Chromebook when I click the icon it opens chrome://extensions

I can't find resources on how to handle this. The app is a dropdown in the top menu bar of Chrome, but can be opened as a "Popup".

Comment: "The app is a dropdown in the top menu bar of Chrome," — are you sure it's an app, not an extension?

Comment: I define the browser_action in the manifest to be a "popup" to open a page, could this be an issue? This makes it an extension if I'm correct. I've ran into this issue before for sure. If I remember correctly, an app will actually launch a new page but an extension launches a new page and goes to chrome://extensions when pinned. 

In the GSuite it specifically says:

"Pinned Apps and Extensions
Locally applied
0 apps or extensions will be pinned to the Chrome launcher if they are installed. Manage pinned apps"

Is there an event to listen for to handle when a pinned ext is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

I think there can be any permission denial or anyother issues related to popup of the page kindly lookup through this link 
https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/1375694?hl=en   also try to avoid popup and find another best method